# LibreOffice Writer 4 theme problem

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

After upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 writer disappeared so I installed it via software center but now my Writer look like this:

[image]

How to revert to default theme so it looks exact like rest of system. I'm using Ambience theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not install the full LibreOffice suite. In particular you are missing libreoffice-gnome (and libreoffice-gtk, but that will be installed by libreoffice-gnome). In general, it is a good idea to do a full:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

to get the full suite (even the Ubuntu default install contains only a partial installation).